# How to process various levels of items in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I need to process various levels of items in Spring Batch.
For each item level, I need to read new data and process it in a nested way.

For example, this 3 levels (country, csv list, csv):

```
read country...
process country... 
write country: foreach country {
   read csv list..
   process csv list..
   write csv list: foreach csv list {
      read csv...
      process csv...
      write csv...
   }
```

As first aproach I have managed to do it in a single job (with one read-write step), buy now I am trying to separate it in different jobs (because I want to re-use some methods, implement repositioning, multithread, and so on).

I have seen that there is a way to launch jobs inside other job:

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("nestedJobStep").job(getNestedJob()).build();
```

But this is valid only for sequential steps/jobs. I need a Job to be launched inside another, because it will process a single item of other job (for example, a csv from a csv list from a country).

So I think that the solution is to launch a job directly inside the write method of the step of the parent job:

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends OperationalCountry> list) throws Exception {
    for (CtbOperationalCountries item : list) {
        writeItem(item);
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void writeItem(OperationalCountry item) throws Exception {
    jobLauncher.run(getProcessCsvListJob(), createJobParameters(item));
}
```

In order to be able to launch a second job inside another I needed to do this in my JobRepositoryFactoryBean (otherwise I get a java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository):

```
factory.setValidateTransactionState(false);
```

Now I can launch nested jobs, but it stucks while reading the second item (processCsvListJob) of the nested job. It seems that it is not creating new transactions...

In the AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean javadoc says:

> public void setIsolationLevelForCreate(java.lang.String isolationLevelForCreate)

> Flag to determine whether to check for an existing transaction when a
> JobExecution is created. Defaults to true because it is usually a
> mistake, and leads to problems with restartability and also to
> deadlocks in multi-threaded steps.

So maybe this is not the way of working with spring batch, or I am not configuring the transactions correctly, or I am missing something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Two important points are worth mentioning in your case:

- In the chunk-oriented processing model of Spring Batch, the design of what an "item" is is crucial. Items should be carefully designed as this would impact the correct choice of the item reader, processor and writer. Encapsulation is key here.
- The chunk-oriented processing model is ***not*** suitable to every use case. In your requirement, I see a read operation in the write phase:  `[...] write country: foreach country { read csv list.. [...]`. This is a sign that the chunk-oriented model is probably not suitable, or the design of your algorithm is not compatible to be implemented with a chunk-oriented step.

That said, I do not see the requirement to use nested jobs with a single step each. A single job with different steps is more suitable IMO. One would design a job if there is a need for restartability, etc. But in your case, there is no such need for those nested jobs.

The way I would approach this kind of specific requirements is by first trying to come up with an algorithm independent from Spring Batch (ie ask yourself how I would do it ***without*** Spring Batch), then try to implement it with what Spring Batch provides (simple takslets, chunk-oriented tasklets, etc).